# How do I stop Angular 2 router from appending the same route

Tags: node.js, express, angular, angular2-routing

How do I stop Angular2 router appending the same route twice when i refresh the page? It might be something other than angular router.

Go to the root of the app it redirects contact, which is good.
**localhost:3000/contact**

Refresh the page and it appends the same route

**localhost:3000/contact/contact**

the express server only contains 2 routes handlers. Return static files and for everything else return the index.html file.

```
app.get(/\.\w{2,4}$/, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, req.url));
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

index.html has base href set

```
<base href="/">
```

This is the angular route config

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

Comment: I doubt the code in your question causes the issue. Can you please provider more information (other routes, ...). Can you reproduce in Plunker? How does it behave with `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: Hey Günter, It can't be reproduced in Plunker as the issue happens when I refresh the page and the issue is local to my environment. If it helps the files came from this plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/HEoqGVNga8s5tO4niNfg?p=preview via the angular site. I was looking at how ngModules worked as it all changed since RC4. So I took the files from this plunk and added a very simple express server .

Comment: The linked Plunker doesn't contain anything.

Comment: My bad. Please try now:)

Comment: Yup, Plunker contains the files now but I have no idea what could cause your problem.

Comment: If you don't know, then I'm quietly confident I won't either :)

Comment: I haven't done much with the router in combination with modules, especially lazy loaded ones. So don't give up easily just because I don't know ;-)

Comment: I found the issue, posted below. I wasn't looking hard enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue in the index file. This was overwriting my base setting...

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```